# Tableau Missing Permissions

Tags: tableau-api

When trying to add permissions (beyond view) to my collection, I simply do not see any permissions to add. There are no unlicensed users in the server/site and the creator is using a 'creator' license. I've tried searching but havent found anything. I'm not sure if having any 'viewer' licensed persons is what is preventing this but even when I explicitly add another 'creator' it still shows only the 'view' permission. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsKGi.png) of what I do see.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Turns out, I was attempting to change the permission settings on a personal space collection and not a project. I've just reuploaded as a project and can now set the permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to close this question but this solved the problem for me.